# MongoDB.Driver version breaking changes

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am migrating from MongoDB.Drivers 1.10.0.62 to 2.4.4  and found couple of breaking changes,

1. MongoDatabase class is present in `1.10.0.62` and missing in `2.4.4` => what is equivalent class for this?
2. Query class is present in `1.10.0.62` version and absent in `2.4.4` =>

Similarly, what are the breaking changes between these two versions ?

Appreciate your help

Comment: This is for C# .net

Comment: See http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/upgrading/

Comment: what is the equivalent for  = > new MongoClient().GetServer().Shutdown();

'MongoServer' does not contain a definition for 'Shutdown' and no extension method 'Shutdown' accepting a first argument of type 'MongoServer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Already I have reference for MongoDB.Driver.Legacy.dll => Version 2.4.1